# Bounding a variance in a $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebra

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a unital $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebra and $\varphi\in\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{A})$ a state. Define the $\phi$-variance of self-adjoint $a\in\mathcal{A}$ by:
$$\sigma_\phi(a)^2=\phi((a-\phi(a)1_{\mathcal{A}})^2)=\phi(a^2)-\phi(a)^2.$$

Fix $\phi\in\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{A})$ and let $\omega_\phi\in\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{A}^{**})$ be its extension to the bidual. Denote by $\mathbf{1}_E(a)\in\mathcal{A}^{**}$ the spectral projections of $a\in\mathcal{A}$. Suppose that for $\lambda\in \sigma(a)$ and for all $\varepsilon>0$, where $B_\varepsilon=(\lambda-\varepsilon,\lambda+\varepsilon)$ and $p_\varepsilon:=\mathbf{1}_{B_\varepsilon}(a)$:
$$\omega_\phi(p_\varepsilon)>0.$$
Then for each $\varepsilon>0$ define $\phi_\varepsilon\in\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{A})$:
$$\phi_\varepsilon(b)=\dfrac{\omega_\phi(p_\varepsilon b p_\varepsilon)}{\omega_\phi(p_\varepsilon)}\qquad(b\in\mathcal{A}).$$
(Note that the limit $\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\phi_\varepsilon(b)$ [does not exist in general](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/450349/conditioning-a-mathrmc-algebra-state-with-infinite-precision?rq=1)).

I am saying something here like "$\phi_\varepsilon$ $\varepsilon$-localises $a$ near $\lambda\in\sigma(a)$."

Given these conditions, I am hoping to bound $\sigma_{\phi_\varepsilon}(a)\leq f(\lambda,\varepsilon)$. I have a proposition below, but I am concerned about how I am handling ***the extension of $\varphi$ to $\omega_\varphi$, where I am situating elements in a closure of $C(\sigma(a))$ in something like $L^\infty(\sigma(a),\mu_\phi)$, where $\mu_\phi$ is coming from functional calculus, and there is an unresolved tension here considering I am using the bidual.***.

**Proposition:** Given the conditions above,
$$\sigma_{\phi_\varepsilon}(a)^2\leq 4\varepsilon|\lambda|.$$

**'Proof'** Fix $\varepsilon>0$ and let $\varphi:=\phi_\varepsilon$. If we consider the $\mathrm{C}^*$-subalgebra $\mathrm{C}^*(a)$ generated by $a\in\mathcal{A}$ we have $\mathrm{C}^*(a)\cong C(\sigma(a))$, and the restriction of any state $\phi\in\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{A})$ is given by integration against a Radon probability measure $\mu_\phi$:
$$\phi(b)=\int_{\sigma(a)}\pi(b)(t)\,d\mu_\phi(t).$$
Here $\pi:\mathrm{C}^*(a)\to C(\sigma(a))$ is transformation, and under this transform $a\mapsto [t\mapsto t]$.

By assumption, $\omega_\phi(p_\varepsilon)>0$. ***I want to say that***:
$$\omega_\phi(p_\varepsilon)=\int_{\sigma(a)}\mathbf{1}_{B_\varepsilon}(t)\,d\mu_\phi(t)=\mu_{\phi}(B_\varepsilon)>0.$$

***I also want to say that***:

$$\omega_\phi(p_\varepsilon a p_\varepsilon)=\int_{B_\varepsilon} t\,d\mu_\phi(t),$$

which yields the bounds:

$$
\begin{aligned}
(\lambda-\varepsilon)\mu_\phi(B_\varepsilon)\leq &\, \omega_\phi(p_\varepsilon a p_\varepsilon)\,\leq (\lambda+\varepsilon)\mu_\phi(B_\varepsilon)
\\\implies (\lambda-\varepsilon)&\leq\varphi(a)\leq (\lambda+\varepsilon)\
\end{aligned}$$
Similar methods, with $\pi(a^2)=[t\mapsto t^2]$ then yields:
$$\begin{aligned}
(\lambda-\varepsilon)^2&\leq\varphi(a^2)\leq (\lambda+\varepsilon)^2
\\ \implies\sigma_{\phi_\varepsilon}^2=\sigma_\varphi(a)^2&=\varphi(a^2)-\varphi(a)^2
\\ &\leq(\lambda+\varepsilon)^2-(\lambda-\varepsilon)^2=4\varepsilon\lambda.
\end{aligned}.$$

This is for $\lambda>0$. For negative we end up with the absolute value. We need $\varepsilon<|\lambda|$.

For $\lambda=0$, it is

$\sigma_\varphi(a)^2\leq \varepsilon^2$.

> **Question:** Does this analysis check out?

Comment: I’m assuming $a$ is self-adjoint? In any case this seems reasonable to me, you could just work in $\mathcal{A}^{**}$ from the start and everything checks out.

Comment: @DavidGao yes $a$ is self adjoint.

Comment: In that case everything seems fine. You could just work in $\mathcal{A}^{**}$ from the very start. Essentially, you could just start by saying $\mathcal{A}$ is a vNa and $\phi$ is a normal state and you never need to mention the double dual. Then everything checks out.

Comment: @DavidGao how does that go exactly? Can I identify the image of the Borel functional calculus in the von Neumann algebra generated by $a$? Which is commutative. Do I have a result then that says the algebra is an $L^\infty(\sigma(a))$, and do I have the characterisation on states here as integrals with respect to a measure? That makes sense to me. I can restrict then to the isometric embedding back in the original algebra.

Comment: @DavidGao there is something strange going on with $\lambda=0$.

Comment: Ah! Things are interesting there! Because we can't bound the integrals so easily!

Comment: Technically, the result saying the image can be identified as an $L^\infty(\sigma(a))$ only works if your vNa is separable. Generally that's the case people consider, but since you're dealing with double duals, that's usually not true. However, Borel functional calculus still works even without that identification. Indeed, if your vNa acts on Hilbert space $H$, then for each pair of vectors $h, k \in H$, $C(\sigma(a)) \ni f \mapsto \langle h, f(a)k \rangle \in \mathbb{C}$ defines a complex measure $\mu_{h, k}$.

Comment: Therefore, for each bounded Borel function $f$ on $\sigma(a)$, $(h, k) \mapsto \int f \mu_{h, k}$ defines a bounded sesquilinear form on $H$ and therefore induces an operator $f(a)$. This is how Borel functional calculus works in the first place. Noting that any normal state $\phi$ (emphasis on *normal*) is induced by a trace-class operator easily tells you $\phi(f(a)) = \int f \mu_\phi$ holds, or, if you want, you can just choose the universal normal representation of your vNa, then any normal state is a vector state and this just becomes part of the definition of Borel functional calculus.

Comment: I really only looked at the part with double dual, but yeah, your later bounds on the integrals only work for $\lambda > 0$ and $\varepsilon < \lambda$. If $\lambda < 0$ and $\varepsilon < |\lambda|$, your bounds should become $|\varphi(a)| \geq |\lambda| - \varepsilon$ and $\varphi(a^2) \leq (|\lambda| + \varepsilon)^2$, so $\varphi(a^2) - \varphi(a)^2 \leq 4\varepsilon|\lambda|$. If $\lambda = 0$, you bounds should become $|\varphi(a)| \geq 0$ and $\varphi(a^2) \leq \varepsilon^2$, so $\varphi(a^2) - \varphi(a)^2 \leq \varepsilon^2$.

Comment: @DavidGao yes I noticed these since you first commented and edited accordingly. If you would like to summarise your comments to answer I will accept and thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are my comments, summarized into an answer:

Everything is fine. Indeed, one could just work in $\mathcal{A}^{∗∗}$ from the very start. Then the question becomes when $\mathcal{A}$ is a vNa and $\phi$ is a normal state, whether the argument works out. You never need to mention the double dual in that case, and everything checks out.

For technical details on the Borel functional calculus, if the vNa in question is separable, then the image of Borel functional calculus is an $L^\infty(\sigma(a))$. But this doesn't always work in the non-separable case. People usually only consider the separable case, but since we're dealing with double duals, that's usually not separable. However, Borel functional calculus still works even without that identification. Indeed, if your vNa acts on Hilbert space $H$, then for each pair of vectors $h, k \in H$, $C(\sigma(a)) \ni f \mapsto \langle h, f(a)k \rangle \in \mathbb{C}$ defines a complex measure $\mu_{h, k}$ on $\sigma(a)$. Therefore, for each bounded Borel function $f$ on $\sigma(a)$, $(h, k) \mapsto \int f d\mu_{h, k}$ defines a bounded sesquilinear form on $H$ and therefore induces an operator $f(a)$. This is how Borel functional calculus is usually defined in the first place. Noting that any normal state $\phi$ (emphasis on *normal*) is induced by a trace-class operator easily tells you $\phi(f(a)) = \int f d\mu_\phi$. Or, if you want, you can just choose the universal normal representation of your vNa, then any normal state is a vector state and this just becomes part of the definition of Borel functional calculus.

For the bounds on integrals, the original bounds on the integrals only work when $\lambda > 0$ and $\varepsilon < \lambda$. If $\lambda < 0$ and $\varepsilon < |\lambda|$, your bounds should become $|\varphi(a)| \geq |\lambda| − \varepsilon$ and $\varphi(a^2) \leq (|\lambda| + \varepsilon)^2$, so $\varphi(a^2) − \varphi(a)^2 \leq 4\varepsilon|\lambda|$. If $\lambda = 0$, your bounds should become $|\varphi(a)| \geq 0$ and $\varphi(a^2) \leq \varepsilon^2$, so $\varphi(a^2) − \varphi(a)^2 \leq \varepsilon^2$.

Comment: Adding reference. Extensions from state of $\mathcal{A}$ to normal state of $\mathcal{A}^{**}$ and to positive trace-class operator of $B(\mathcal{H})$ are  described in Schaefer "Topological Vector Spaces", ch 6, 7.1 corollaries 2 and 3 (check proofs).